# Can't delete file in XCode from project

Tags: xcode

After updating XCode, I was unable to delete files from project.
I press "Move to trash", and nothing happenes.
I still can access to file in project tree.
How can I do that?
Maybe, I need to check some options?
Please, help me.

[image: XCode screenshot]
[image: XCode about]

Comment: Try restarting it, just some boolean gone crazy...

Comment: I already did it, and restarted the computer too.

Comment: Are you able to spot it in Finder using 'Show in Finder' command? Are you sure there are no access restrictions on the file or enclosing folder?

Comment: In finder I can do it. But it should work directly from XCode.

Comment: My question to you is - does XCode lead you to correct file? If yes, check the access restrictions on file. If no, you must just remove the reference from project and add again. Then try doing Trash from XCode.